# css - stick div to the center when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe embedded into my page. There is a div inside the iframe which needs to always stay in the center of the screen, even when I scroll.

My page is set up in a way that iframe fits completely, without scrollbars:

**main page:**

```html
...
<body>
    ...some content
    <iframe src="test.html" width="200px" height="700px">
    </frame>
    ...
</body>
...
```

**test.html:**

```html
...
<div class="modal_window">
    <p>Very important message</p>
</div>
...
```

How can I make my `div.modal_window` always stay in the center of the screen (if the iframe is visible on the screen, of course)? Preferably using css only

Comment: that doesn't seem to work inside iframe :(

Comment: Give it for the `<iframe />`

Comment: In the "center of the screen" or in the center of the iframe? Because staying in the center of the screen may not even be possible if the iframe is not intersecting that center.

Comment: center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal_window{
   position:fixed;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:block;
   z-index:100;
}
```

This code 
`margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;display:block;` will keep your div in center of parent div.

and `z-index:100;position:fixed` will keep the division on top of parent div and fix position.